# Have custom object which I can see in workbench, but not in the Salesforce UI

Tags: custom-object

Have custom object which I can see in workbench, but not in the Salesforce UI - anyone seen this one?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Checked your profile permissions on that object? Are you seeing it because you have sys admin view all or is it configured on the object as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list in Workbench contains both Custom Objects and Custom Settings. If it's not showing up on the Custom Objects screen in UI then it is likely to be a Custom Setting.

Custom Settings can be found in the UI under **Setup > Develop > Custom Settings**.

Comment: That was it, too close! Didn't think about that